# mysql fror mac, create databases ERROR 3680 (HY000)

Tags: mysql

when i type

```
create database test;
```

it shows

> ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'test' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

what is problem and what i can do ?

Comment: What is the code you're trying to execute?

Comment: @BenM It's in the question: `create database test;` It wasn't as easy to see before I reformatted the question, but it was there.

Comment: It sounds like MySQL isn't installed properly.

Comment: Have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206435/mysql-8-0-mac-creat-database-issue